# Cordova file get filename from error?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using the cordova plugin cordova-plugin-file to read and save files. I'm reading a file like this:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory+__filename, onFile, onFail);
```

In the event the file does not exist, an error code 1 will be returned.

```
function onFail(__file_error){
    console.log('load error', __file_error.code);        
}
```

I've traced __file_error but I cannot seem to find the original filename in it? Since I don't seem to be able to pass any optional parameters between resolve and onFail, how do I know for which file it failed??

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    cordova.file.dataDirectory+__filename, 
    onFile, 
    function(){console.log(__filename);onFail}
);
```

Sorry, on my phone so syntax may not be 100%, but you can call a function where you specify the fail, so function, log error (or something else), then call onFail and get error code.

Comment: It's a good idea but I won't have __filename from onFail since I cannot pass extra parameters to onFail. So I'm basically back with 2 functions. I'd like to have both the error code and the filename in the same function...